# What's the correct way to pass -fuse-ld=lld in a Boost user config file?

Tags: c++, boost, clang

I am using a toolchain setup with [msvc-wine](https://github.com/mstorsjo/msvc-wine#use-with-clanglld-in-msvc-mode) to compile Windows binaries on Linux.

I mostly have everything working, but there's one thing I'm unsure about - how am I supposed to pass the "-fuse-ld=lld" flag to clang-cl?

Here's my user-config.jam:

```
using clang-win :  : clang-msvc.sh :
<manifest-tool>llvm-mt
<compileflags>/std\:c++17
<compileflags>/EHa
;
```

clang-msvc.sh is a wrapper which loads the required environment variables before invoking clang:

```
#!/bin/bash

BIN=~/.cmake/toolchains/msvc/bin/x64 . ~/git/msvc-wine/msvcenv-native.sh

clang-cl $@
```

My question is, where in the boost configuration do I specify the -fuse-ld=lld option? I've tried adding a `<compileflags>` and `<linkflags>` option, but neither had an effect.

The only way I've found is to add it as part of the wrapper script, but I feel like it should be possible to pass it in the user-config.